# Iterative function not accumulating properly for GFS daily heatwave counter animation in Earth Engine

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, weather

I am building a animation where the intent is to first create daily means out of GFS for temperature, then convert each day into a mask meeting a temperature threshold, and then applying a iterative accumulating function so that each image in the image collection shows how many days up to then has a particular pixel reached that temperature threshold.

So a pixel may have a value of 1 for day 1 in the image collection, but then 2 in day 2, while another pixel next to it goes from 0 to 1, as temperatures expand and linger over multiple days. One could then see a heatwave grow and deepen as temperatures stay high.

My script currently calculates and creates a daily counter fine, but the iterative script does not work. I suspect it is some sort of casting error, but I am not sure.

Here is my code as a snapshot:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/4496d1248712e2c31ecf5501e6cfcc27

Here is the entire script:

```
/*
Data goals: convert GFS to daily, create consecutive and iterative day counters for 
pixels that meet set temperature thresholds

ex. a GIF that shows by day how many days up to then have reached tk temperature.
*/

//set bounds for data extracts, GIFS
var bounds = geometry 

//start and end dates
var startDate = ee.Date('2023-07-01')

var endDate = ee.Date('2023-07-31')

//pull GFS data, filter to forecast_hour = 0 (actual data, and one value per hour) and temp
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('NOAA/GFS0P25') 
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date(startDate, endDate))
                  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('forecast_hours',0))
                  .select('temperature_2m_above_ground')
                  
// Calc number of days between start and end dates.
var nDays = ee.Number(endDate.difference(startDate, 'day'));

// Enumerate a list of days.
var daysList = ee.List.sequence(0, nDays.subtract(1));

// Map over the list of days to make daily mean composites.
var NEXDayListCol = ee.ImageCollection(daysList.map(function(dayN){
  var t1 = startDate.advance(ee.Number(dayN), 'day');
  var t2 = t1.advance(1, 'day');
  var date = t1
  var dailySum = dataset.filterDate(t1, t2).mean();
  return dailySum.select('temperature_2m_above_ground').multiply(1.8).add(32)
  .set('date', date.format())
}));     

//mask out below 95 F (32.2C)

var masked  = NEXDayListCol.map(function(image){
  return image.mask(image.gte(95));
});

//create counter raster

var counter = masked.map(function(image){
  return image.where(image.gte(0),1).rename('count').toFloat().copyProperties({
        source: image,
        properties: ['system:index','date']
      });
})

 
print(masked,'masked counter')

// Get the timestamp from the most recent image in the reference collection.
var time0 = masked.first().get('date');

print(time0,'time0')

var first = ee.List([
  ee.Image(0).set('date', time0).select([0], ['count'])
]);

print(first,'first')

// This is a function to pass to Iterate().
// As anomaly images are computed, add them to the list.
var accumulate = function(image, list) {

  var count = ee.ImageCollection(ee.List(list)).sum()

    .set('date', image.get('date'));
  return ee.List(list).add(count);
};

print(accumulate,'accumulate')

// Create an ImageCollection of cumulative anomaly images by iterating.
// Since the return type of iterate is unknown, it needs to be cast to a List.
var cumulative = ee.ImageCollection(
  ee.List(counter.iterate(accumulate, first)
  ))

print(cumulative,'cumulative')

// Define GIF arguments
var gifParams = {
  collection: cumulative,
  dimensions: 100,
  framesPerSecond: 4,
  region: bounds,
  crs: 'EPSG:5070',
  palette: ['e6eff9','f5eeda','fdc47c','f9a224','ee3a43','black'],
  min: 0,
  max: 10,
}

// Define arguments for the getFilmstripThumbURL function parameters.
var filmArgs = {
  dimensions: 100,
  framesPerSecond: 4,
  region: bounds,
  crs: 'EPSG:3857',
  min: 0,
  max: 30,
  palette: ['blue', 'purple', 'cyan', 'green', 'yellow', 'red'],
};

var dayVis = {
  min: 1,
  max: 30,
  palette: ['black','red'],
};


Map.addLayer(counter.sum(), {},//dayVis,
'daily sum total test');

print(ui.Thumbnail(cumulative,gifParams))

//print(cumulative.getFilmstripThumbURL(filmArgs),'cumulative')

//print(NEXDayList_Col.getFilmstripThumbURL(filmArgs))
```

If you replace

`print(ui.Thumbnail(cumulative,gifParams))`

`with print(ui.Thumbnail(counter,gifParams))`

It works. The issue is in the cumulative script.